# Show that $e^{1/x^2}$ is not a distribution in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

In homework I have to do prove that, but $e^{1/x^2}\in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\})$ and therefore a distribution, isn't it? I am confused.

Comment: On $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ it is a distribution, but not on $\mathbb R$. I don't think that we even can extend it to a distribution on $\mathbb R$ by trying to remove the infinity at $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the most common convention, a locally integrable function *induces* a distribution. Now pick any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. The function $x \mapsto \exp(1/x^2)$ is of class $C^\infty(K)$, and therefore integrable on $K$. It defines a distribution in a canonical way, and we say that it *is* a distribution.